# How to modulazire both i18n and envs in automation teeting. (Typescript Playwright Cucumber)

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, automated-tests, internationalization, config

My app has 3 envs: `TEST`, `STAGE`, `PROD` and also 3 languages. I would like to create a general config file with common consts as url stub, api stub, then env specific files. I could use npm config for this. Last thing I would need would be the I18n specific strings, perhaps in json?

Should I create separate config files for both envs and i18ns (strings may differ accross envs) or create 9 config files (`test_en`, `test_de`, `test_nl`, `stage_en` and so on...). What would be the best way of achieving that. What tools to use? Import default config as json, envs with `config` and i18n files?